# How to update libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.26)(64bit) to 2.27 and more on OPENSUSE LEAP15.2 linux distribution. Opensuse, php8-fpm, php8, apache2

Tags: php, apache2, glibc, opensuse

I updated the php7 to php8 and I tried to install php8-fpm (nginx) or apache2, but
during installation, I am getting this error:

> *Problem: nothing provides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)' needed by the to be installed php8-fpm-8.1.5-lp153.63.1.x86_64
> Detailed information:
> nothing provides 'libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.27)(64bit)' needed by the to be installed php8-fpm-8.1.5-lp153.63.1.x86_64
> Solution 1: do not install php8-fpm-8.1.5-lp153.63.1.x86_64
> Solution 2: break php8-fpm-8.1.5-lp153.63.1.x86_64 by ignoring some of its dependencies*

Then I tried to upgrade my glibc2.26 to 2.27 and I got another warning:

> *Warning: Repository 'Online updates for openSUSE Leap:15.2 (standard)' appears to be outdated. Consider using a different mirror or server.*
> *Reading installed packages...
> 'glibc' is already installed.
> **No update candidate for 'glibc-2.26-lp152.26.12.1.x86_64'. The highest available version is already installed.**
> Resolving package dependencies...*

When I did my search on the internet to find a new ***libc*** package that would be compatible with my Linux distribution OPENSUSE LEAP15.2 , I found that there is no version higher than 2.26.

**Any recommended resource or solution for being able to host a web server on libc-2.26 or Update this libc to a higher version**?

[image]